# JPA @Discriminator : how to cast one entity into another (based in discriminator)

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to have a User table with different types of users. I have a user class and then i extend it by Customer and Employee and Manager and admin and they all reside in the same table Users but they all have different discriminators.

Now my application is such that first a user comes in and signs in as a User then he either becomes a customer or an employee. after a user has been created a customer or an employee, I want to change later on into manager or admin. how can I update that. how can I make the discriminator value different from what the entity originally had.

I can use simple sql to update the DTYPE value in my table but I am pretty sure JPA must have some way that is more efficient.

Or do I have delete the previous say "employee" user and create a new "admin" user. I tried instantiating the entity but it doesnt give me any method where I can update the Discriminator for that entity.

Thanks
Syed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it would be better to model roles of `User` (such as `Customer`, `Employee`, `Manager`, `Admin`) as a separate entity having one-to-one relationship to `User` (or many-to-one, if `User` may have several `Role`s simultaneously). Then, if role of the user changes, you can simply delete one role and create another.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make copy-constructors, and instantiate a new object, like:

```
new Employee(existingUser);
```

Thus the identifier (`@Id` field) will be copied, and when persisting the entity, an update will be triggered. Try it.